# DisallowedHost at / Error: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'domain.com,domain.com' - How to Resolve?

Tags: python-3.x, django, nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu-22.04

I'm encountering an issue with my web application where I receive the following error message:

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'domain.com,domain.com'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.

This error occurs when I try to check the URL. I'm using Django for my web application. The server is running Ubuntu 22.04 with nginx as the web server and hosting is being managed using Gunicorn.

I've already checked the domain configuration, and it seems to be correctly set up. However, I'm unsure why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it.

Could someone please provide guidance on what might be causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: domain.com,domain.com is not valid domain name show us https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example